# List shared folder with .bat file

Tags: php, batch-file

I'm trying to list a shared folder in php executing a .bat file this way

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    $current_directory = getcwd();
    $command = "cmd /C $current_directory\\script.bat";
    $files = exec($command);
    var_dump($files);
?>
```

and the bat file

```
net use \\myurl\resources /user:Admin pass
dir \\myurl\resources\50000\Documents\myfolder >> log.txt
```

But the response I get is a string which contains the last line of the bat file,how I can get the list  of the folder content??

Answer (score 0):

Not really the prettiest solution, but you could solve this using [passthru](http://php.net/passthru) and [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$current_directory = getcwd();
$command = "cmd /C $current_directory\\script.bat";

ob_start(); // Start the output buffer
passthru($command); // Execute the command
$files = ob_get_contents(); // Fetch the buffered output
ob_end_clean(); // Stop output buffering

var_dump($files);
?>
```

Comment: Same result, `$files` doesn't containt the comman execution result

Comment: Because you output the `dir` result to `log.txt`. You could lose the `>> log.txt` or just read the `log.txt` using [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)